# Fill entire div with image & make whole div clickable as a link

Tags: html, css

I have a circular div which I'd like to fill with an image & make the entire image/div clickable(href) with the mouse pointer changed to a hand type cursor

I've looked up a few examples & tried the below which doesn't load the image into the div. I'd also like to zoom out the image on hover.

How could I achieve this pelase?

```
<div class="circleDiv">
    <a href='#'></a>
</div>

.circleDiv{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #09f;
  margin: 30px 70px 30px 70px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circleDiv a{
  background: url("path_to_image") no-repeat right center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using `background-size`, `background-position`, `display` and `:hover` pseudo class here is the JSfiddle for the same https://jsfiddle.net/bhfr0t1m/3/

I hope this is exactly what you want

UPDATE:

If you want the square image as circular you can use following code

```css
.circleDiv{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #09f;
  margin: 30px 70px 30px 70px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.circleDiv a img{
  border-radius: 50%;
   transform: translate(50%,50%);
   height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
}

.circleDiv a img:hover{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate(0,0);
   
  }
```

```html
<div class="circleDiv">
    <a href='#'><span><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/6ndnxsbqr/index.jpg"/></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - In the fiddle, the image sits as a square. Is there a way you could scale it to fill the circular div please?

Comment: @usert4jju7 I have updated my jsfiddle just check the updated link in the answer. Actually you have written zoom out in you question which means to reduce size whereas zoom in means increasing the size. Please update your question. Also you can set the `background-size` property to any value as per you convenience (as much you want to scale) in `:hover` css definition.

Comment: @usert4jju7 Updated the answer to convert square image into circular image.

Comment: Hello geeksal - I've bunped into another problem related to filling background color to the page staring from the div clicked. I've created a question here - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232064/html-grow-transition-image-color-to-fill-entire-web-page`. Let me know if you're happy to help please.

Answer (score 2):

you can make entire DIV clickable (not an elements inside it) by using this:

```
<div class="circleDiv" role="button" onClick="location.href='stackoverflow.com'">
```

add this CSS to div class (just to change mouse pointer):

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to the `.circleDiv a`

```
.circleDiv a{
  ...

  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7avvwreq/)

Comment: Thank you smnbbrv. I've updated `https://jsfiddle.net/7avvwreq/` with a working image. If I put a square image, the entire becomes a square instead of remaining circular. The image does not scale down to the size of the `div`. Could you please help fix this one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<a href='https://www.google.fr/'>
   <div class="circleDiv">
   </div>
</a>

.circleDiv{
   position: relative;
   margin: 30px 70px 30px 70px;
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: url("path_to_image") no-repeat right center;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated [your js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7avvwreq/2/)

You need to add a `:hover` for the img as well as a border radius to either the img or the wrapper. Adding it only to the wrapper also requires to set the overflow to hidden.

Comment: Hello noa-dev - I've bumped into another problem related to filling background color to the page staring from the div clicked. I've created a question here - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232064/html-grow-transition-image-color-to-fill-entire-web-page`. Let me know if you're happy to help please.

Answer (score 1):

Looked like fun and a good time to use clip :) I've created a fiddle, but not changed much. The use of clip stops the weird mouse pointer change as you reach the edge of the circle.

```
.circleDiv {
   position: relative;
   background-color: #09f;
   margin: 30px 70px 30px 70px;
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.circleDiv a {
   background: url('https://placeimg.com/500/500/animals') no-repeat center;
  background-size: fill;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(125px at center);
  clip-path: circle(125px at center);
}

/* hover style, could be animated */
.circleDiv a:hover {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yduk2dfc/)

Comment: Cool stuff. Thank you :)